# What should we do with the [implements] and [extends] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There are currently 144 questions with the [implements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implements) tag and 588 questions with the [extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extends) tag. Both have wikis:

> `implements` is a keyword in several programming languages used to denote interface inheritance
>
> `extends` is a keyword in several programming languages used to denote implementation inheritance

but neither of those make me confident that the tags can stand by themselves; I don't see a situation where I'd use these in which [interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaces) or [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) wouldn't already cover it. Should we burn them, or is there a better alternative?

As far as alternatives go, I see that [extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extends) is currently a suggested synonym of [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance), but I don't see anything similar for [implements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implements).

Comment: The wiki for "implements" isn't even correct.

Comment: You said you don't feel confident about them, but you haven't said why they don't fit on Stack Overflow. Questions about software design can be on topic here.IOW you need to bring a stronger argument than "they feel a bit funny or odd" (paraphrasing).

Comment: @slugster I guess all I've said is that "neither of those make me confident that the tags can stand by themselves." The blunt way to put it is that I feel that [tag:interfaces] and [tag:inheritance] probably already cover 99.9% of what these tags would do. I personally don't see how I'd tag with "implements" or "extends" unless I was just throwing buzzwords out trying to get attention. (Though if you can prove me wrong, I'd love to hear it.)

Comment: In general, tags that are keywords in programming languages are fine, as are class and method names in well-known libraries and frameworks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I admit, I was somewhat curious what the stance would be for keywords in general.

Comment: @BoltClock If the ultimate decision is to let these tags be, is the wiki something you'd be willing to fix?

Comment: I fixed the Tag Wiki.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Do you feel like pulling out what you've said into an answer? Just want to fully close the loop and have an answer to look back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, tags that are keywords in programming languages are fine, as are class and method names in well-known libraries and frameworks.

I could see how I might search for `implements` `java` if I were looking for questions in that subject area.