# The things are no longer [uptodate]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

What, if anything, should we do about the [uptodate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uptodate) tag?

The tag has no usage guidance and currently contains 26 questions. Some of the questions concern `UpToDate` which is apparently [a class in the Apache Ant API](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/UpToDate.html) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12963878/397817)), but most are about "keeping *things* up to date".

[One question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1195868/397817) is locked, zero-score and unanswered; [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34365697/397817) is seriously off-topic.

I'm not sure about total burnination because the advice in [this answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/397817) may apply to the Ant questions - "In general, tags that are keywords in programming languages are fine, as are class and method names in well-known libraries and frameworks." I do not feel qualified to judge as I am not familiar with the framework.

Comment: There are different opinions whether keywords, etc., are good tags. [The last discussing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis/360290#360290) I remember gave a clear picture (+32/-1) towards not having methods as tags.

Comment: Kill it with  26 questions is ridiculously small, so even if it's "valid" within a particular framework, it's not widely used.

Comment: Title suggestion: Should we keep (the things) [uptodate]?

Comment: @martin That product looks very domain-specific. I doubt there will be many questions about it that are fit for SO.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Feel free to edit

Comment: @S.L.Barth: That looks like a healthcare product. Also, it does not look like reusable library or framework. I agree that it hardly fit for SO.

Answer (score 7):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

As said in the question, it's heavily ambiguous. It could mean keeping things up-to-date, a particular class in a package, and the questions are often of poor quality.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Potentially, (programming questions around keeping software up to date are on topic), but in this case [we already have a tag for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-update).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Certainly not on its own; there may be borderline cases where it does, but I can't see any on any of the questions using that tag thus far.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope, as above.

So based on the above, I'd say it should go. Considering that it has so few questions however, it's feasible to just [go ahead and clean it up manually.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

Comment: Now that you've provided an answer which covers the "four criteria" - thank you for that - and there are up votes in support, should the question now be tagged [burninate-request]?

Comment: @StephenKennedy, looks like it already was tagged [burninate-request] a few months back (and a couple of months after your comment). Feel free to fo through the list of 24 questions, and retag/close them where necessary.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao - it's almost complete now, but there is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195868/make-visual-studio-stop-rebuilding-up-to-date-projects) which is locked.

Comment: @StephenKennedy And now there's none.

Comment: @BhargavRao Good man, thank you.